# can CloudWatch Agent be installed in Alpine

Tags: dockerfile, amazon-cloudwatch, alpine-linux

Is there an valid CloudWatch Agent package can be installed in Alpine? We want to build a custom docker for CloudWatch Agent on Alpine but the available downloads in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html don't seem to work (I tried some deb or rpm).

Some errors:
failed to install downloaded deb file:

```
/ # dpkg -i -E amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb
dpkg: error processing archive amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb (--install):
package architecture (amd64) does not match system (musl-linux-amd64)
```

and failed to install downloaded rpm file:

```
/ # rpm -U amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
/bin/sh is needed by amazon-cloudwatch-agent-1.247347.6b250880-1.x86_64
```

Any definite answer if Alpine is supported by CloudWatch Agent, or not? Apparently it's supported by CloudWatch Log Agent.

Answer (score 1):

[The issue tracker indicates that the binaries do work](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/issues/115). However, you're trying to install the `deb` and `rpm` packages on Alpine. Alpine uses `apk`. Trying to use `deb` or `rpm` like this will very likely result in a broken system since you're installing packages from multiple distributions on top of each other.

You need to install the binary manually, you can extract it from either the rpm or deb packages.

The linked issue also indicates that only systemd and upstart are supported, so you'll need your to configure start-up yourself (maybe an `init.d` script?).